# Angular2 Array.prototype.map() failing when single object in array

Tags: json, angular, typescript

The below code works fine, when the response returns MORE than 1 object in Json array. Note the Json structure expected is a array of Address objects referenced by property field "address". In other words (addresses.address) below references an Array.

```
public getAddressByPersonName(personName: string): Observable<Address[]> {
  return this.http
    .get(API_URL)
    .map(response => {
      const addresses = response.json();
      if (addresses)
        return (addresses.address).map((address) => new Address(address));
      return null;
    })
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

}

When only ONE address is found, the response returns Json with single Address object. However I get below error during runtime.

> TypeError: addresses.address.map is not a function

The JSON string returned is:

```
{
  "address": {
    "addressId": "1",
    "addressLine1": "5 Bayberry Close",
    "personName": "Dr John",
    "route": {
        "routeId": "100",
        "routeName": "45 Main Street",
        "updateBy": "admin",
        "updateDate": "2017-07-03T17:48:33-04:00"
    },
    "updateBy": "admin",
    "updateDate": "2017-07-03T18:10:27-04:00"
  }
}
```

What is the reason for above runtime error ?

Comment: Because in that case it's not an array, so it doesn't have a map method? Have you looked at the JSON you're getting back?

Comment: Please post the JSON you are getting

Comment: Added returned JSON. So the  function has to change to both handle single vs multiple items returned ?

Comment: There were 2 answers to this question, and both are correct. I found many sample code and tutorials where angular2 page expects to render a list of items and, uses a REST get call to fetch data. Could not find any example where single json object vs multiple objects in a Array scenario is handled as in the case I had to. So does this mean my backend service that returns json structure is not implemented correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are trying to map an object, but the [map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is only for arrays.
What you can do is check if the given response is the expected array response or not and wrap the object inside an array in case it's already one.
as followed:

```
getAddressByPersonName() {
  return this.http.get(API_URL)
    .map(response => {
      const addresses = response.json();
       if (addresses) {
         if(!Array.isArray(addresses.address)) {
           addresses.address = [addresses.address]
         }
           return (addresses.address).map((address: Address) => new Address(address));
       }        
       return null;
   })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As we can see, the JSON you are getting if it's returning just one object, is in fact an object and not an array, and we cannot use `map` on an Object. Since it works for several objects, I assume your JSON response then returns an object `address` with an array:

```
{
  "address": [{ ... }, { ... }]
}
```

So what we can do, is check if the response is indeed an array, and if so, do mapping. If not, then just cast the response to an object matching your class. For consistency I think you want to return the single object in an array (?) to avoid type missmatches, so do something like this:

```
getAddressByPersonName() {
  return this.http.get(API_URL)
    .map(response => {
      const addresses = response.json();
       if (addresses) {
         if(Array.isArray(addresses.address)) {
           return 
               (addresses.address).map((address: Address) => new Address(address));
         } else {
            return [new Address(addresses.address)]
         }
       }        
       return null;
   })
}
```

Comment: This solution will also work and is a good one; I have tested it. However, I accepted the other solution since it modifies returned json and uses same return call. This highlights more clearly the original issue, that  returned json from backend service comes in two formats.

Comment: @Nirmal581 Yes it's totally your choice which answer to accept. I wouldn't have even written an answer if the author of the accepted answer would have originally provided that answer, now it looks like almost an exact copy of that one, but I'll leave it here tho :P